# How to use the "Least square method" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I need to determine the values of ceofficients in my equation. For that I decided to use the least square method. The equation is presented below:
[image: My equation]

The equation presents a connection between stress and time to failure of a tested product at different temperature levels. The data that I've used is made up, but presents the structure of the actual data, that I will use later on.
For better understanding I also included a graphical correlation:
[image: Graphical correlation of stress and time]

I am fairly new to python so I didn't know that there so many ways/functions of this method availible, so I decided to try out a few:

**Input data**

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, fit_report

# data
temp =np.array([650, 700, 750, 720, 680]) # temperature
xdata = np.array([500, 525, 540, 534, 490]) # time
ydata = np.array([330, 332, 315, 325, 335]) # stress
T = temp[0]


plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'*')
plt.xlabel('xdata')
plt.ylabel('ydata')
```

**1. Using the curve_fit function**

```
def func(logS, a_0, a_1, a_2, T_a, logt_a):
    return  logt_a + (T - T_a) * (a_0 + a_1 * logS + a_2 * logS**2)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
popt

zapis = 'a_0: {0:1.5e}\na_1: {1:1.5e}\na_2: {2:1.5e}\nT_a: {3:1.5e}\nlogt_a: {4:1.5e}'.format(popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4])
print(zapis) 

a_0 = popt[0]
a_1 = popt[1]
a_2 = popt[2]
T_a = popt[3]
logt_a = popt[4]

residuals = ydata - func(logS, a_0, a_1, a_2, T_a, logt_a)
fres = sum(residuals**2)
print(fres)

curvex=np.linspace(np.min(xdata)-np.min(xdata)/10, np.max(xdata)+50,    np.max(xdata)/10)
curvey=func(curvex, a_0, a_1, a_2, T_a, logt_a)
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'*')
plt.plot(curvex,curvey, 'r')
plt.xlabel('xdata')
plt.ylabel('ydata')
```

**2. Using the leastsq function**

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def function(parameters, logS):
    a_0, a_1, a_2, T_a, logt_a = parameters
    model = logt_a + (T - T_a) * (a_0 + a_1 * logS + a_2 * logS**2)
    return model

def objective(pars, t_r, logS):
    err =  t_r - function(pars, logS)
    return err

x0 = [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ] #initial guess of parameters
plsq = leastsq(objective, x0, args=(ydata, xdata))

print('Fitted parameters = {0}'.format(plsq[0]))
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ro')
#plot the fitted curve on top
x = np.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata), 50)
y = function(plsq[0], x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'k-')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

In both cases I got this results:

```
a_0: -5.95683e+02
a_1: 2.65405e-02
a_2: -2.63017e-05
T_a: 1.21502e+02
logt_a: 3.11614e+05
```

**Question 1:** What is the best way of determing the initial values of the searched coefficients?

**Question 2:** Which of the methods in python, that is based on the least square method is the best for equations like in my case?

**Question 3:** Is there a way to make the process of determing the coefficients as parameters more automated? Because I will have to try out also higher order polynomials which will lead to more coefficients (a_3, a_4, a_5,...). The idea would be to write the order of the polynomial and everything else would then be calculated and formed by itself.

Comment: I can't give definitive feedback on this, but some things that might (?) help. Have you to see if both methods are the same speed (since you suggest they both converge on same solution but I wonder if they do the same thing under the hood)? In regards to point 3, is [polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) suitable as it minimises squared error and you can specify the order?